# Should I change my HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I am using a WD Blue PC HDD 2.5" and I was having random crashes and was getting I/O errors. So I downloaded the official dashboard tool of Western Digital and my HDD failed the short and extended tests. Since I do not have much idea about what do these numbers mean, I am attaching the screenshot of S.M.A.R.T values of my HDD.

[image]

Comment: It is 3111 degrees celcius, roughly the temperature at which rhenium starts to melt.... That is almost 3 times hotter than lava.

Comment: On a more serious note, yeah it is time to replace that HDD. Perhaps switch to an SSD if you care more about speed than space. https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-a-reallocated-sectors-count Back your files up.

Comment: That is a worrying number of reallocated sectors. Copy off what you can and bin the drive.

Comment: Those WD Blue drives start off OK then they degrade in performance after a year. We had many of them in all the workstations at my workplace. After replacing them all with SSD's the machines are back to top performance on the user experience side. I'd not invest in another spinning disk unless you have a specific need for it. Get an SSD :)

Comment: thanks to all those who replied, I'll be replacing it with an m2 NVME SSD tomorrow. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly 10000 reallocated sectors in a barely new drive with not even 3 months running time indicates severe dammage. Replace that drive.

If you have data left that has not been backed up either use ddrescue to duplicate the drive or use a professional recovery service.

The WD dashboard is visibly a pretty useless tool as even WD itself is not able to correctly decode and print SMART parameters containing more than one value (194 temperature).

Seeing just a sixth of alle available attributes is disappointing, using the command line tool smartmontools is the way to go:
Running
`smartctl -a /dev/sdx > myreport.txt` after replacing the `x`by the drive letter in question is the necessary command.

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10910

It is strange that this tool does not print a regular WD model number like `WD10JPVX`. Do they want to hide something - like the identification of a unreliable SMR drive p.e.?

Comment: BTW, use a tool such as free *HW Info* or * CrystalDiskInfo*, which shows *Normalized Values* for Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology (S.M.A.R.T.) data. Normalized values are easier to understand: more is better, 100 is the "norm" in most cases.

Comment: "Normalized Values" are theoretically sound but practically useless. Not convinced? Read the google study about drive failures and the Backblaze statistics. I ignore normalized values.